# Stop infinite caching of a single object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I have a simple rails app that was running fine till yesterday. But it is showing very unique behavior now by caching the same object again and again because of which the page is not getting loaded. When I hit the Url I get this in development console and it keeps going on and on.

```
Started GET "/store" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-02 12:26:27 +0530
Started GET "/store" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-02 12:26:27 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by WelcomeController#store as HTML
Processing by WelcomeController#store as HTML
  Category Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Category Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Category Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (28.4ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (28.4ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.5ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (12.8ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (12.8ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.1ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.1ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (16.7ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (16.7ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (14.8ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (14.8ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.0ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.0ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (14.3ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (14.3ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (11.3ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (11.3ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (15.1ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (15.1ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.0ms)
  Rendered welcome/store.html.erb within layouts/application (13.0ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
```

This keeps going on and on.

I have written these three lines to fetch categories/category in my action for two different objects which I need.

```
@categories = Category.all
@category = Category.first
@category = Category.where(:search_index => params[:s_i], :keyword => params[:key]).first if params[:s_i]
```

I have not even enabled caching in my development.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

The strange thing is that it is running fine onn my staging server on heroku.

I have tried the following commands but nothing seems to help.

```
Rails.cache.clear

rake tmp:cache:clear
```

I will be really very thankful if someone helps me understand what is going wrong.

I am using `Rails 4.2.5` and `Ruby 2.2.3` on `Ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: it looks like you are rendering `welcome/store.html.erb` over and over again.  Look at parts of the code that render that template.

Comment: oh and the `CACHE` you see there has nothing to do with the rails cache.  It's activerecord's way of doing the same sql query in the same request.

Comment: @jvnill Thanks for this. Any idea why is this query might be getting repeated.

Comment: usually when an infinite loop happens, you're calling the template inside itself.  try commenting out the whole file then slowly uncomment parts of it.

Comment: I m sorry but i did that procedure at first.